# Which city is depicted on Ubuntu 16.04 default night cityscape wallpaper?

Tags: 16.04, default, desktop-background

The image below is one of the default wallpaper images on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. According to [this link](https://www.ostechnix.com/default-set-wallpapers-ubuntu-16-04-lts/), it is called: *Night lights by Alberto Salvia Novella*

Does anyone know in **which city** it was taken?

[image]

Comment: New york city...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was taken in New York, New York, USA. Citation: https://www.flickr.com/photos/138596056@N03/23769648846

Please note the artists tags, among others, `new` `york` `manhattan` `empire` and `state`.

Answer (score 4):

I took the photo in Manhattan, from the Empire State Building, during the World Police and Fire Games 2011.

You have to know that the city really looks like that at night, it's not a visual effect. I took the photo wanting it to look somehow natural.